# PHP: Replacing two items in the same str_replace

Tags: php, string, str-replace

Sorry for the bad English. As I know, I can only replace one character/word/sentence for another one when using `str_replace()`.

I have the string "`5.501,82`" inside a two-position array. I first replaced the `.` for a blank/white space.

So now I want to replace the comma before the 82 for a point. Is there any chance to replace it in the same `str_replace()`?

I have already tried this:

```
str_replace('.', '', ',', '.', $dolarcompra[1]);

str_replace('.', '', $dolarcompra[1]), str_replace(',', '.', $dolarcompra[1]);
```

I'm using a function to create a line that only allows seven parameters, and `$dolarcompra` is the last one.

Comment: Take a look at `strtr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array.  But order matters here. See how the `.` is replaced first so that you don't end up replacing the ones that replace the `,`?  You don't want to replace `,` with `.` and then replace those `.` with `''`:

```
$result = str_replace(array('.', ','), array('', '.'), $dolarcompra[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try that